# Making 2D arrays larger than 100x100 in processing 3

Tags: arrays, processing

So I'm just in my first weeks of uni and they've been putting us through a "coding bootcamp" to get everyone up to speed and make sure they know the basics. At the end of the bootcamp, we're supposed to show off a project showcasing our knowledge and what we learnt. We've been given a list of suggested things of what we could do and I decided to do mine based on [the amazing, autotuning sandpiles](http://nautil.us/issue/23/dominoes/the-amazing-autotuning-sandpile).

To do this I figured I could make a 2D array of grains which could then allow me to something along the lines of this to simulate the shifting sands:

```
for(int i=0; i<cols; i++){ //for every column in the array
  for(int j=0; i<rows; j++){ //for every row in the array
    if(grain[i][j].value>=4){ //if the grains of sand on that square are greater than 4
      grain[i][j-1].value=grain[i][j-1].value+1; //add a grain to the square above
      grain[i+1][j].value=grain[i+1][j].value+1; //"                       " to the right
      grain[i][j+1].value=grain[i][j+1].value+1; //"                       " below
      grain[i-1][j].value=grain[i-1][j].value+1; //"                       " to the left
    }
  }
}
```

That's not the code in question I have an issue with, just there to show the gist of what I'm trying to do, though any pointers won't go amiss.

what I've got at the moment is as follows
A class for the grains of sand:

```
class Grain{
  PVector position;
  float size;
  int value;
  color colour;

  Grain(float x, float y){
    position = new PVector(x,y);
    size = 5;
    value = 0;
    colour = color(grain0);
  }

  void draw(){
    stroke(0);
    fill(colour);
    rect(position.x,position.y,size,size);
  }
}
```

And then the main body of the code:

```
color grain0 = color(255);
color grain1 = color(255,0,0);
color grain2 = color(0,255,0);
color grain3 = color(0,0,255);
Grain[][] grain;
int cols = width;
int rows = height;

void setup(){
  size(600,600);
  grain = new Grain[cols][rows];
  for(int i=0; i<cols; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<rows; j++){
      grain[i][j] = new Grain(5*i,5*j);
    }
  }
  println(cols, rows);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  for(int i=0; i<cols; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<rows; j++){
      grain[i][j].draw();
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is stemming from the fact no matter what I do the array doesn't seem to get any bigger than 100x100, despite stating it should be widthxheight. Is this a built in limitation of processing, or is there some step I'm missing? I've looked elsewhere but I haven't been able to find anything that seems to match my problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is no problem having an array of size larger than 100x100 (which only has 10,000 entries). Whatever the problem with your code is, it isn't due to any limitation to the size of an array that Processing can handle. Eventually (with truly large arrays) you will exceed the capacity of your computer to handle it, but you are well below that threshold. Note that you are sizing your array *before* determining the sketch size in `setup()`, which really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documention](https://processing.org/reference/size_.html) on `size()` says that "If size() is not used, the window will be given a default size of 100 x 100 pixels." You haven't yet called `size()` when you have the lines

```
int cols = width;
int rows = height;
```

so you are just assigning those default values.

The simplest fix is to just get rid of those variables and have the line

```
grain = new Grain[width][height];
```

in `setup()`. There really isn't any need to have aliases for `width` and `height`. At the very least, you should delay the assignment of `cols` and `rows` until after your call to `size()`.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like a bit of an idiot now xD

I'd put it in as a variable so that I'd be able to resize it should the points be too small or something, but evidently, I put them in the wrong spot.

I've now initialised them as global variables and then given them values after I set the size, but now this is making everything disappear, any idea why that might be?